# How to detect jack insertion in a 3.5mm socket

Tags: pcb-design, audio

I'm designing a custom PCB for a hobby project that includes a 3.5mm jack connector (PJ-3420, schematics below) which receives audio from a DAC (PCM5102). I'd like a way to detect that a jack has been inserted into the socket. Using a multimeter I have confirmed that pins **3-6** and **4-5** are **connected** by default, and **disconnected** when the jack is inserted.

The part I don't get is that pins 3 and 4 are receiving audio signal, so I don't see a simple way to detect the state of the switches.
Technically I could use a pullup on pin 6 and read the analog value on my MCU, assuming that audio output is never going to reach VCC but that seems overly complex and requires using an ADC from the MCU.

I've picked one of the most available connectors I could find on a popular PCB prototyping service, but others connectors seems to be working this way as well.

[image: photo]
[image: schematics]
[image: PCM]

Comment: There might be several options, but to be sure, describe the situation more. Where do the audio wires go, to a DAC maybe, and why it needs to detect an inserted jack, and does it need to detect that anything is connected on the other end like headphones or amplifier, or just that empty plug is present? Some DACs have already a feature for detecting plugs. Which DAC is it?

Comment: Just FYI, these jacks are designed to disconnect speakers when headphones are inserted.

Comment: Are there any DC levels on the DAC output or, is it capacitively coupled? Ditto where the received signal goes?

Comment: @Justme I've added the schematics and the PCM reference. I need to detect that a jack is inserted to power-on/off a separate amplifier + speaker circuit (right now a PAM8304)

Comment: @Andyaka I might be answering wrong since I'm pretty new to electronics, but the Jack ground is the same as the rest of the circuit so I'd say that the output signal is balanced around it and there is no DC offset?

Comment: @trethaller The DAC output has zero DC offset. And to throw more opportunities or problems, I believe that's a TRRS connector for headsets. Do you need to be compatible with headsets too or only TRS plugs? Also the DAC does not have detection or does not care. What complicates things is that when DAC is off or sleeping, the DAC outputs are not driven to 0V, so detection must not rely on this.

Comment: Why not use a jack that has a switch on the ground contact? That makes detection a lot easier.

Comment: @Hearth thanks, do you have any recommendation of jack connectors that have a switch on the ground contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect a 47 kΩ load resistor R1 to your analog input you can detect the status of the switch inside the jack.

As long as there is nothing plugged in (SW1 closed), M2 is conducting. That ensures M1 is off.

An open SW1 turns M2 off and M1 on.

There is a 1.3 µA standby current in the OFF state flowing trough R2 and R3, which would drain a battery on the long run. Not very elegant but hard to avoid.

A capacitor of, say, 10 nF, parallel to R2 may be useful as ESD protection for the gate of M2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frevcO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, a lot, trying to understand this - when SW1 is open, M2 receives VCC/2 and is swiched on. When SW1 closes, assuming that AUDIO_IN never gets above VCC, tension on the gate is always below the switch threshold. Regarding R1, is the idea that it should be high enough comparing to headphones resistance (which are say <30 ohms) to avoid reducing the headphones output, but low enough to turn off M2 when SW1 closes ?

Comment: @trethaller There might be a misunderstanding. I assume the switch is open if something is connected.

Comment: right, when the jack is inserted, the switch opens. Maybe it's confusing that I talked about audio signal coming-in ? right now I'm sending audio signal continuously to the 3+4 pins (probably connected to AUDIO_IN in your schematics) and I was concerned about this interfering with the M2 detection logic. Bear in mind that I might be missing very obvious things!

Comment: @trethaller You can add a resistor of 47 kohm in series with the switch and a capacitor of 10 uF parallel to R2 or from gate of M2 to GND. This would cancel out the AC signal components of your audio line seen by the gate of M2.